# Socket programming using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I have a desktop application on which im using socket in .NET but now i want to change desktop application to web app.
When i try to use socket in ASP.net it is not working is there any solution for that?
and is it possible to send/receive through TCP using ASP.Net because web is stateless??

Comment: see the SignalR on Github

Comment: You may get a better response to this if you post an example of your socket not working in ASP.Net (see sscce.org)